# Running docker inside a container in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: docker, containers, pipeline, aws-codebuild

I got a Java application. In local, I can connect to Dev Container using Visual Studio Code. Now I wanna build a CodePipeline in AWS. But it displays an error like this when I tried to start docker in CodeBuild's Ubuntu standard 7.0 container:

> [Container] 2023/05/20 12:13:06 Running command sudo service docker
> start /etc/init.d/docker: 96: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation
> not permitted)

Please help. Here's my buildspec.yml:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - cat /etc/os-release
      - sudo apt update -y
      - sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
      - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
      - echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
      - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
      - sudo apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose
      - sudo service docker start
  build:
    commands:
      - docker-compose up -d
```

My build image:
[image]

Comment: Can you show where is your build agent image section, you many need to add `privileged: true` in order to run docker containers inside build server.

Comment: @AnkushJain Yes, I have added ss of my CodeBuild's image. Please take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tick that highlighted **privileged** checkbox, and save the latest configurations.

You can see, it is already mentioned there that you need to enable this flag in order to build docker images inside the CodeBuild agent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. How silly of me, you're truly life saver. I'm able to run it now.